# linux dual monitor setup each connected to intel and nvidia gpus

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, xorg, gentoo

My computer is intel 9600k + vertical monitor + z390 chipset + nvidia rtx 2060 + horizontal monitor + Gentoo linux + Xorg server 1.20.6 + gnome 3.32.2

In the UEFI i've set intel iGPU as primary GPU.

`gnome settings -> Devices -> Display` wouldn't report the monitor connected to the nvidia GPU. So i tried to manually configure the `Xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
 Identifier "layout"
 Screen      0  "iGPU" Absolute 0 0
 Screen      1  "dGPU" Absolute 900 0
 Option         "Xinerama" "1"
# Option "AllowNVIDIAGPUScreens"
EndSection

Section "Device"
      Identifier "iGPU"
      BusID  "PCI:00:02.0"
      Screen 0
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # This identifier would be the same as the name
    # of the connector printed by xrander.
    Identifier  "DP-3"
    Option      "Rotate"    "right"

    Option  "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
    # A line such as this ^ may be necesary if you
    # are not getting your prefered resolution.
    # These numbers need not be reversed with tallscreen orientation.
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # This identifier would be the same as the name
    # of the connector printed by xrander.
    Identifier  "DP-4"

    Option  "PreferredMode" "1360x768"
    # A line such as this ^ may be necesary if you
    # are not getting your prefered resolution.
    # These numbers need not be reversed with tallscreen orientation.
EndSection

Section "Device"
      Identifier "dGPU"
      Driver "nvidia"
      BusID  "PCI:01:00.0"
      Screen 1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
     Identifier "iGPU"
     Device "iGPU"
     Monitor "DP-3"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
     Identifier "dGPU"
     Device "dGPU"
     Monitor "DP-4"
EndSection
```

but after the grub loader on primary monitor, both the screens just go blank.

`/var/log/xorg.0.log` says `specify BusID` though I've specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting your `BusID` lines like this:

```
BusID  "PCI:0:2:0"
BusID  "PCI:1:0:0"
```

I've been searching similar setups recently. I cannot remember where I saw it, but there was an explanation that these numbers are decimal, not hex as printed by `lspci`. And, all should be separated by colons with no extra (i.e. leading) zeros.

I cannot authoritatively comment on whether having Intel as the primary GPU in the firmware is correct, though, I would suspect that is the correct setting for that.

edit:
found the source for my comment about decimal:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1102560